# Display a list of non-archived related news with Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, tx-news

I'm trying to show a list of **related** news articles in detail view (working) but I want to render "only non-archived entries"

Is this possible with Fluid and how? Maybe with filters?
My code is pretty standard. Nothing special:

```
...
<f:for each="{newsItem.allRelatedSorted}" as="related">
<li>
<span class="news-related-news-date"><f:format.date format="{f:translate(key:'dateFormat')}">{related.datetime}</f:format.date></span>
<n:link newsItem="{related}" settings="{settings}" title="{related.title}">
{related.title}
</n:link>
<f:render partial="Detail/FalMediaContainer" arguments="{media: related.falMedia, settings:settings}" />
<f:render partial="Detail/MediaContainer" arguments="{media: related.media, settings:settings}" />
</li>
</f:for>
...
```

Thank you!